# How to determine if a specified time has elapsed without user activity

Tags: c, windows

How to determine if a specified time has elapsed without user activity in windows using any language like screen savers do?

Comment: Clearly it's possible, since screen savers do it.  :-)  Presumably you're asking *how*.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows you could use the function [GetLastInputInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to detect if the user is idle.

Assumedly your main application would run in the background checking for user idleness at intervals. When the appropriate idleness is detected it would launch, for example it's screen saver functionality.